# Show UIView with xib on textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, addsubview, custom-view

I made a custom uiview class with a xib and I want to be able to show it on the screen with textFieldDidBeginEditing but I can't seem to figure it out.

In myCustomView:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //Load the interface

    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customNib", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

**What I did and works is in IB I put a view in my interface and linked it to my customView class.**

Now, I want to show this view with custom class programmatically.

If I do this in my textFieldDidBeginEditing (I have a textfield in my main view):

```
var myView: myCustomView = myCustomView(frame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

I get a red square on the screen but it does not "load" the xib.

Am I not asking the good question or am I doing something wrong? Could you guys poit me in the right direction?

I went through all the similar questions here and could't find the solution.

Comment: If you create a custom view with xib then you have to load it using this `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customNib", owner: self, options: nil)` then assign its frame and then add it to subview. What results you are getting while doing this?

Comment: You can put that answer as an answer to your question than accept it... You never know when someone might make the same mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just the stupidest of the things, i initialised myView with init(frame) and hadn't put my xib on the screen. This works:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customNib", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)
}
```